# Sharepoint 2010 Javascript Client OM, get user data (not current user) via javascript object model

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, jquery

There are plenty of examples of getting the current user via javascript object model in SharePoint 2010, but I am looking for help with getting any users email/title when I have the loginName.

There is a user collection but I think you use the site groups to get to it? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the GetUserProfileByName operation in the UserProfileService SOAP web service. The easiest way to do this in JavaScript is to use the SPServices jQuery plugin. The information provided in the documentation linked below should be enough to get you started.

[UserProfileService.GetUserProfileByName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofileservice.getuserprofilebyname.aspx)

[$().SPServices GetUserProfileByName Documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetUserProfileByName)